# Passing UsbDeviceConnection to other Activity

Tags: android, usb

I'd like to pass the UsbDeviceConnection object from one activity to other activities to provide a USB communication on other activities. How can I share the usb connection between different activities in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Singleton class that manages all communication via the USB connection.  That way you can send messages from anywhere you like.

Comment: Thank CaseyB. I will try the Singleton class.

Comment: If that works for you it would be great if you would accept this answer.